# context menu for printing the page printing the context menu itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, contextmenu

I am building a context menu on a page that has just one picture and I want users to have only two options whey they right click: print or close the page.
Everything works fine except when they print it, the context menu gets printed as well.
How do I remove the menu as soon as print is clicked so it is not printed?
Here is a fiddle:

View: http://jsbin.com/eQiToLA/2

Edit: http://jsbin.com/eQiToLA/2/edit

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#imgContainerDiv').vscontext({menuBlock: 'vs-context-menu'});
   });
```

My markup here:

```
<body>
  <div id="imgContainerDiv">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-8.jpg" alt="city" />
  </div>
  <div class="vs-context-menu">
   <ul>
       <li class="print"><a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;" id="menu_1">Print</a></li>
       <li class="exit"><a href="#" onclick="window.close();return false;" id="menu_2">Close</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS Print Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing) can be used to apply styles for printing.

```
@media print {
    .vs-context-menu {display:none;}
}
```

or you can have a seperate stylesheet

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css"
     href="print.css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a print stylesheet that hides any elements you don't want printed.

Typically a print stylesheet will optimize the page for reading on paper, such as removing the header image, setting the text to black on white, and removing any non-essential elements.